Wait until column value changes in Firebird 4 UDR
I need to return some information in a stored procedure, but to get the information in this stored procedure, I need to wait a column to be changed in a specific table. For example:
Table Structure:
TABLE_BI
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL (PK)
  PROCESS_ID INTEGER NOT NULL (PK)
  FINISHED BOOLEAN

My stored procedure starts. In the beginning it adds a record:
INSERT INTO TABLE_BI (PROCESS_ID, FINISHED) VALUES (1, FALSE) RETURNING ID INTO :SAVE_ID;

Now, I need to wait until FINISHED field become TRUE, and than return some values.
We have a service that should change FINISHED to TRUE, but it take some seconds.
I need to create a UDR function in Delphi to do it. I've already created a DLL library exporting the firebird_udr_plugin function, but I have no idea which interface to implement in my class that will do it, like IEventCallback, IEvent, or IMessageMetadata.
Can anyone give me a tip on how to do it?
I saw this post on GitHub that someone was trying to do something similar:
https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues/7455
User asfernandes says to use the wait_event function as an example, available here:
https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/master/examples/udr/Functions.cpp#L38
But it's not clear to me.

TLDR: You cannot do that. Put whatever you want to do after changing of the field into a "after update" trigger.

Your stored procedure/transaction will not see those changes, so trying this is moot. It is a bit unclear to me exactly what you're trying to achieve here, but a design where your stored procedure doesn't need to wait is probably better. Actions to be done when the processing is finished should be handled in a different way (after update trigger as user13964273 suggests, or waiting for an event in your application/and or polling the table is probably a better way.

Also, Stack Overflow works better for clear questions, not vague "give me tips" and "its not clear to me" questions. You may want to consider asking on firebird-support instead.

Hello @MarkRotteveel, I'm sorry for not being clear. Well, I need to wait because this Stored Procedure should be use by other db users, that would be for BI purposes (Busines Inteligence). So when this user calls this stored procedure, it must returns the value, but it will take some seconds. It's like a dashboard, that needs to refresh after some seconds, and this Stored procedure to return these values.

If you need values after some seconds - request them after some seconds. Don't try to use a client-server DBMS as something else.
